# How do I get a list of all lowest directories with the absolute path?

Tags: find, directory, absolute-path

I'm trying to copy a directory structure(not the files) for backup and migration. I've been searching all over but I don't quite know how to phrase my search to get the results I want. I keep finding people mentioning the following commands the second being closest to what I am trying to get. I need to make sure it runs in KSH and BASH.

```
ls -Rl |egrep '^d'
and
find / -type d -print
```

An example of the file structure and how I'd like to get a list of all the lowest(?) directories with their full path prefix.

```
/var/www
└── site
    ├── dir1
    │   ├── dir11
    │   ├── dir12
    │   ├── dir13
    │   │   └── dir131
    │   └── dir14
    ├── dir2
    └── dir3
        ├── dir31
        └── dir32
            └── dir321
                ├── dir3211
                └── dir3212

##### Will generate the following list. #####

/var/www/site/dir1/dir11
/var/www/site/dir1/dir12
/var/www/site/dir1/dir13/dir131
/var/www/site/dir1/dir14
/var/www/site/dir2
/var/www/site/dir3/dir31
/var/www/site/dir3/dir32/dir321/3211
/var/www/site/dir3/dir32/dir321/3212
```

Thank you,
LF4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing ls -R | grep ./ will give the list of all directories and subdirectories and could be fed into something else which will mkdir for all the entries.

This assumes you are in the directory /var/www/html. You could alter the grep so that instead of ./ it uses /var/www/html or whatever.

Comment: Another way I could do it is with find as followed.  find . -type d -print |grep -v .svn |egrep -v '^.$'  but it still would list all directories. So what you're saying is I need to use sed to remove the parent directories?

Comment: so you don't want to have dir1 and dir3 in the listings? surely if you're doing backup you'd want them to do mkdir dir1, mkdir dir11 etc?

Comment: I wanted to make it faster by just doing mkdir -p which would create all parents if they don't exists.

Comment: fair comment, but not sure how much quicker it would make it. If you explicitly doing mkdir for the parent folders then the -p flag wouldn't need to check if the parent existed on all of the subdirectories which to me indicates it'd be slowed down. There's (probably) more subdirectories than directories. But I am just speculating.

Comment: Very good point. This might be to much of a hassle (after 5 mins of searching it was more a "There has to be a way to do that!" then this is what I want to do since I could do it the simple way. Thanks. :)